# Is there a page with a list of specialist badges?

Tags: support, badges

[This page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) only contains generic badges. Is there a page with a list of specialist badges?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Click the tags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) next to general.

Comment: Oh, you all just *knew* there was going to be some Paint action here.

Answer (score 2):

You mean [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags)? It's the next tab along on the main tags page.